# Best way to fill a list with an adapter in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

I developed an app which fills a list. It works fine in the way I did it but I'm not conviced that I solved the problem in a recommended way. I read that you should override onActivityCreated in a Fragment and fill the list there instead of doing this in onCreateView. onCreateView should only be used to inflate static views. Is this true? If yes, how should these two methods look like in the end?

This is my Fragment class:

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    List<MyItem> items = createListItems();
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(view.getContext(), items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                    "Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    });

    return view;
  }
.
.
.
}
```

My MainActivity just adds the fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentMain fm = new FragmentMain();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_main_container, fm).commit();

    }
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is true to a certain extend only because onCreateView happens on the UI thread and you don't want anything slowing that down otherwise your UI will be slow and choppy. For example, in your fragment class you have a call to a method "createListItems()". I don't know how many items you're making but if it's a lot it could slow down your UI (especially if youre accessing a database and querying objects and so on). So you could do it in onActivityCreated but you could also use an AsyncTask. So your code would become something like this:

```
public class LoadListObjectsTask extend AsyncTask<Void, List<MyItem>, Void> {

  private MyListAdapter myListAdapter;
  private Context mContext;

  public LoadListObjectsTask(Context context) {
     this.mContext = context;
  } 


  @Override 
   public void doInBackground(Void...params) {
     //create your list objects here instead of on UI thread. This will run on a separate thread.
   myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(mContext, items);
   return items; //return list of MyItems
   }


   //This is called when doInBackground is done. THIS WILL RUN ON THE UI THREAD So don't do 
   //anything slow here
   @Override 
   public void onPostExecute(List<MyItem>...params //don't really need the list here//) {
     listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
   }
}
```

then in your fragment

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

   //new code
    new LoadListObjectsTask(getActivity()).execute();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                    "Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    });

    return view;
  }

 public void onResume()... {
  //also add the task here so your content is reloaded on resume..
  new LoadListObjectsTask(getActivity()).execute();
 }
.
.
.
}
```

If you don't want to do this just make your List of MyItems a private field and move

```
List<MyItem> items = createListItems();
```

to onActivityCreated().

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It gives me an idea where to go. I implemented an AsyncTask and everything works fine. Nevertheless, I have still some questions: I create my items in doInBackground and create my adapter and set it to the listView in onPostExecute like you suggest it. To do this, I need the context and the listView of my Fragment in my AsyncTask class. Thus, I added them as class variables and initialize them in the constructor. This means, in my Fragment onCreateView method, I call: new LoadEventsTask(view.getContext(),listView).execute(); 
Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: That is a great way to do that, but also keep in mind that on post execute works on the UI thread so if your listview is a field of your class, your async task can access it. In onPost execute your  async task also has access to the context but what you did works. Also, if my answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: Currently my asinctask class file is in a different file (so not included in the fragment class). Is it recommended to include it in the fragment class file to have access to the views??

Comment: That is up to you. If thats how you want it to work. Its just a matter of personal preference. If its working the way it is set up now i would just leave it. Theres no reason to change it